# Text does not go multi-lines when in Row in a ListView?

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to display conversations messages, and for this I have a ListView, and each elements are rows with the text display and a expanded widget, to keep the text being on the good side.

However, my texts keep overflowing and does not go multiline.

Here is a reproducing example that shows the issue :

```dart
ListView.builder(
  itemCount: 1,
  itemBuilder: (ctx, i) => Row(
    children: const <Widget>[
      Text("very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very long text"),
    ],
  ),
);
```

How can I allow my text to go multiline ? I've been looking for answers already but none of them match my case.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap Text widget with `Expanded` to get available space or `Flexible` to minimum space.

```dart
ListView.builder(
  itemCount: 1,
  itemBuilder: (ctx, i) => Row(
    children: const <Widget>[
      Expanded(child:
            Text("very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very long text"),)
    ],
  ),
);
```

Comment: I've seen this solution everywhere, but it does not work in my case. 
Here is the full widget tree : 
Scafold > FractionnalySizedBox > Center > FutureBuilder > ListView > Row [Expanded, Container > Padding > Text]
As said, the expanded allow to put the container to the right.

Comment: consider updating the question with full sample widget that will reproduce the same error